# Database connectivity problem

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have deployed my web application on www.aspspider.com (which also support MS SQL server db), while connecting to the database, it is giving me an error. So what changes should be made in the connection string, so as to make the connection possible.

Error Message:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: This is almost certainly a configuration error.  Voted for moving to serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all connectivity problems working with SQL Server can be resolved by referring to the excellent Microsoft resource: [Troubleshooting Server and Database Connection Problems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156468.aspx).

If having exhausted these avenues you still require assistance then let us know.